# Beam Kafka consumer metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam

Beam KafkaIO doesn't use the native kafka offset, therefore I cannot use kafka consumer metrics directly.

Wondering what would be the right way to expose those metrics of my KafkaIO pipeline?
Things I am interested includes:

- bytes-consumed-rate
- fetch-latency-avg
- commit rate
- consumer lag

Instead of using the beam metrics, I think another approach might be enable `commit_offset_in_finalize` and then use the Kafka metrics directly? But not sure why this is not enabled by default, is there any concern when enable this? Thanks

Comment: `records lag` and `consumer lag` are the same, no? And Beam should use the consumer offsets topic, and therefore you can use tools like Burrow.

Comment: Beam has its own offset tracking. Unless i enable the auto commit, using kafka metrics won’t work. But given that the auto commit is default to false, I wonder if there’s any potential impact when turning this on. If we don’t enable auto commit, how people tracking these metrics in beam?

Comment: The impact would depend if there's competing logic for where to resume the consumer in the case of restarts. If Beam uses subscribe+seek rather than manual partition assignment, then maybe you'd want auto commits. However, automatically committing doesn't guarantee that those offsets had all been successfully processed. In my opinion, there's little reason not to enable native Kafka consumer commits.